# Error when compiling with compass , File to import not found or unreadable

Tags: css, styles, sass, compass

When I run compass compile I get:

```
    error sass/styles.scss (Line 39 of sass/wh-base/_imports.scss: File to import not found or unreadable: components/productNavigation.
Load paths:
  Compass::SpriteImporter
  /var/www/web/styles/sass
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.rc.1/stylesheets
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/susy-2.1.3/sass
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sassy-maps-0.4.0/sass
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/breakpoint-2.4.6/stylesheets)
Compilation failed in 1 files.
```

This is my  "gem list info"

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
breakpoint (2.4.6)
chunky_png (1.3.1)
compass (1.0.0.rc.1)
compass-core (1.0.0.rc.1)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
ffi (1.9.3)
fssm (0.2.10)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
minitest (4.3.2)
multi_json (1.10.1)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
rb-inotify (0.9.5)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rubygems-update (2.4.1)
sass (3.3.14, 3.3.12, 3.2.19)
sassy-maps (0.4.0)
susy (2.1.3)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
```

I tried with other gem versions (latests) without any results.

I'm using ruby 2.0.0

Any help?

Comment: I cloned the file repo in another machine and it compiles, I installed the same gems with the same versions without any luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the files had capital letters not present in the import. For some reason, my version in one machine was case insensitive.